# PowerShell StreamWriter path property

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

Is it possible to take an existing StreamWriter variable and see the path that it is using? So far as I can tell (using Get-Member on the variable) the answer is no. Just wanting to verify I am not missing something, since this seems like a property that should be accessible.

For a little context, I am reworking my logging system, which currently uses Add-Content and can slow things down when appending to longer files. So I want to switch over to a StreamWriter based approach. However, I also use two log files, one local in Temp at initialization, and another potentially on the network, that I start working with after I have validated some XML based settings, which includes the path to the final log file. So I need to be able to switch log paths. I already have the path changing in a script scope variable, which I access using a Getter and Setter. My thought was to have a Getter for the Writer as well, and check the path to see if it matches the current log path, and if not, close the old log and open a new one. But I don't see any way to see what the path of the StreamWriter is.

EDIT: Based on the comment from @bluff, I switched from

```
$script:pxlogWriter = New-Object io.streamWriter (Get-PxLogFile)
```

to

```
$script:pxlogWriter = New-Object io.fileStream (Get-PxLogFile), 'Append', 'Write', 'Read'
```

But still no Path property.

EDIT2: Correction. no path property, but the Name property is... the path. WTF can't Microsoft be at least a little logical and consistent? Sigh. Anyway, I now have my Singleton working. So that's progress.

Comment: As far as I know a streamwriter just writes to a stream: it has no underlying logic of knowing what the stream does with the data (and it shouldn't) since it can be a filestream, memorystream, networkstream etc. If you are using a filestream you can check the path in the filestream property, the streamwriter however shouldn't have anything to do with this part.

Answer (score 0):

A `StreamReader` instantiated with a path string [doesn't save this path](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,227). So no, there's no way to obtain the path. Store it in a different way, for example in a `Tuple<string, StreamReader>`.

The [same goes for a `StreamWriter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,180).